# how do i access nested html elements using selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

i am using a  school class schedule  website and i want to access the div element  that contains info on how many seats are in a class and who is teaching it in order to scrape it.  i first find the element which contains the  div element i want, after that i try to find the div element i want by using xpaths. the  problem i face is  when i try to use  either the find_element_by_xpath or find_elements_by_xpath to get the div i want  i get this error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

is this error happening because the div element i want to find is nested? is there a way to get nested elements using a div tag?

here is the code i have currently :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = "https://app.testudo.umd.edu/soc/202008/INST"
driver.get(url)
section_container = driver.find_elements_by_id('INST366')

sixteen_grid = section_container.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class = 'sections sixteen colgrid']").text
```

the info i want is this:

```
<div class = "sections sixteen colgrid"</div>
```

its currently inside this id tag:

```
<div id="INST366" class="course"</div>
```

greatly appreciated if anyone could help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_elements#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_id) of `find_elements_by_id`:

> Returns : list of WebElement - a list with elements if any was found. An empty list if not

Which means section_container is a list. You can't call find_element_by_xpath on a list but you can on each element within the list because they are WebElement.

What says the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=find_elements#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_id) about `find_element_by_id`?

> Returns : WebElement - the element if it was found

In this case you can use find_element_by_xpath directly. Which one you should use? Depends on your need, if need to find the first match to keep digging for information or you need to use all the matches.

After fixing that you will encounter a second problem: your information is displayed after executing javascript code when clicking on "Show Sections", so you need to do that before locating what you want. For that go get the `a href` and click on it.

The new code will look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://app.testudo.umd.edu/soc/202008/INST"
driver.get(url)
section_container = driver.find_element_by_id('INST366')
section_container.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='toggle-sections-link']").click()
sleep(1)
section_info = section_container.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='sections sixteen colgrid']").text
driver.quit()
```

Comment: god bless you for the help

Comment: i was wondering, how do i make it print out text on the console?. the code works, but it doesnt seem to print out the actual text on the jupyter notebook. i was hoping of parsing it to get the info i need. EDIT: i was able to figure it out. thank you for everything and stay safe during this time.

Comment: `print(section_info)` for this example. (I wrote it anyways in case someone else wonders the same)

Comment: What does the dot mean in ".//a[@class='toggle-sections-link']"? It seems to not work without it